# Concatenate across columns and rows using group and listagg in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have a table like below and would like to group across columns and then rows. 
I have a solution that somewhat works but is very slow. Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Thank you

```
| GROUP | VAL 1 | VAL 2 | VAL 3 | 
|   A   |   1   |    2  |   3   |
|   A   |   4   |   5   |  6    | 
|   B   |   7   |   8   |   9   |
|   C   |   10  |   11  |   12  |
```

Preferred result is

```
| GROUP | TEXT |
|   A   |123456|
|   B   | 789  |
|   C   |101112|
```

This is what I currently have but it is very slow. Is there an alternate solution which groups across columns and rows

```
    select GROUP,
    listagg(comments,',')
    within GROUP (order by GROUP) "TEXT"
    from
    (select concat(val 1,concat(val 2,val 3)) as Comments, data.* 
    from data)
    group by GROUP;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following query where you will directly get concatenated column values:

```
SELECT
    "GROUP",
    LISTAGG(VAL_1 || VAL_2 || VAL_3)  
        WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY VAL_1) AS "TEXT"
FROM DATA
GROUP BY "GROUP";
```

**Note**: Do not use oracle reserved keywords as the column names. Here `GROUP` is the oracle reserved keyword.

Cheers!!

Comment: @glencloncurry . . . Although this query is definitely a simplification of your query, it should have the same performance as your query.  I understand the question as wanting improved performance.